# bash -- Isolate specific URLs into an array from string

Tags: arrays, string, bash, loops, grep

I am fairly confident with bash scripting, however this seems a little over my head.

What I am attempting to do, is take a string -- IE

```
page_content=<div class="contact_info_wrap"><img src="http://example.com/UserMedia/gafgallery/icons/email_icon.png" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="40" /><img alt="" src="example.com/UserMedia/gafgallery/icons/loc_icon.png" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="40" />
```

which was found by using this:

```
 pageCheck="example.com"
 if test "${page_content#*$pageCheck}" != "$page_content"
```

within the `then` I am attempting to take each of the urls in `$page_content`, only containing `http://example.com`, and add them to an array.  Though I honestly don't even know where to start!  I would like to end up with something like:

```
This[0]='http://example.com/the/first/url/containing/example.com'
This[1]='http://example.com/the/second/url/containing/example.com'
This[2]='etc ... '
This[3]='etc ... '
```

Is there a simple efficient way to get this done?

Comment: Could you provide the whole code (including the portion where you read the content you associate with each URL)?

Comment: Not much to show ----  Literally:
`mysql --login-path=myhostalias -Dywpadmin_current_content -e"SELECT page_id, page_content FROM client_content WHERE client_section_id = '$client_section_id'" | while read page_id page_content; do`  -- Then the code you see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
sql_request()
{
mysql --login-path=myhostalias -Dywpadmin_current_content -e"SELECT page_id, page_content FROM client_content WHERE client_section_id = '$client_section_id'"
}

filter_urls()
{
grep -E -o "(href|src)=\"[^\"]*$1[^\"]*" | cut -d'"' -f2 | sort -u
}

declare -a array=()
while read page_id page_content
do
  while read url
  do
     array+=("$url")
  done < <(filter_urls "example.com" <<<"$page_content")
done < <(sql_request)

printf "%s\n" "${array[@]-}" # Just to show array content
```

I am not an expert with `mysql`, I just copy/pasted your commanda assuming it is working.  I assumed you want one array with URLs from all pages read, but the solution can be adjusted easily if you are looking for something else.

Furthermore, I assume your data is read correctly by `read` without changing `IFS` or using the common `-r` option, but this is something you may want to do.

Some points of interest :

- Note the use of process substitution `< <()` which allows reading from the command found inside, a bit like a pipe.  The big difference is it leaves the loop body in the main shell context, therefore allowing variables to be assigned without losing their value after exiting the loop.
- I allowed URLs beginning with `src` or `href`, but I assumed they were always quoted.  If this assumption is not save, you would need to rework the regular expression used.
- The script sorts URLs with `-u` to make them unique on a per-page basis, which is a bit lazy (if you need to make them unique, they probably need to be unique in the array).  Not knowing what you really need, I do not want to add code without being sure it helps rather than obscurs.

Comment: You are correct about the quotes ...  Your answer looks like it'd work ...  I will test it tomorrow and if it works I will accept your answer -- otherwise I will continue this conversation .. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: With a little tweaking, this ended up being exactly what I needed .. Thank you!